# Input fields of type "number" are not displaying any text in Contact Form 7 on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, contact-form-7, custom-wordpress-pages

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out. Its gonna be a complete **newbie** question so kindly forgive me for that but I just cant figure it out.

So, I have built a form using contact form 7 on Wordpress and there is this particular input field for **"number"** isn't displaying the text at all. I have tried giving padding and stuff but still no luck. I just switched to an OceanWP Theme and this bug started. I wasnt having any issues on the previous theme.
I think there is some confliction between the theme and the contact form 7 because I cannot modify the form from the widget. I can only modify by writing custom css.
There are just two input fields where this is occurring - postal code and year of birth (both set at numbers).

[image: !]

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.
The solution was to set min-width: 100% with !important tag. Because the default min-width was overriding the newer one.